# Reading thesis on cone tracing, did the author make a mistake?

Tags: raytracing, mathematics, geometry, raymarching, ray

I am reading [this document](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/559921a3e4b02c1d7480f8f4/t/596773e9f7e0ab3d29bb102f/1499952110561/Mroz+Michael_746.pdf) that talks about signed distance field rendering.

In that document section 6.3, on the topic of cone tracing, it says:

> Cone tracing is an extension of the sphere tracing algorithm. In
>   addition to the ray, a cone is created and expanded in the marching
>   direction. At each sampling step, the current cone radius is compared
>   with the minimum distance from the distance field. If the SDF value is
>   smaller than the current radius, the cone has intersected an object
>   [14]. This incurs very little additional cost to the normal sphere
>   trace, while providing useful intersection information.

In particular: `If the SDF value is smaller than the current radius, the cone has intersected an object`.

Am I reading this wrong? there's no way that's true. Consider the following diagram:

[image]

From that diagram, it seems obvious that for any cone radius $R$ there exists an SDF value $\epsilon$ such that $R > \epsilon$ and the cone doesn't intersect the sphere.

Am I interpreting the document wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s kind of inaccurately stated—by comparing the SDF with a linearly increasing radius, the shape that’s being traced out is a cone with a hemisphere on the end, something like this:

[image: diagram]

At any point along the horizontal center line, if the distance to the nearest surface is less than the current test radius, the cone-plus-hemisphere has intersected that surface.

Comment: Although I agree that that shape does indeed match the description, under which criteria are you saying that's what the document is talking about? I didn't see the mention of the spherical component in the thesis

Comment: What the document’s referring to is an approximation to the actual shape—there isn’t a good word for “the shape formed by sweeping a sphere of linearly increasing radius along a line”, but that shape *looks* basically like a cone and has similar characteristics, so “cone” is close enough.

Comment: Granted—two outer lines should be tangent to the circle rather than attached to its diameter. Harder to draw that, though. :)